# Latex \newcommand for \end{verbatim} et.al not working

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make Latex usable, by introducing some timesavers, but I'm having trouble with defining new commands that terminate environments, completely at random.

This works:
`\newcommand{\bcv}{\ensuremath{\begin{smallmatrix}}}
\newcommand{\ecv}{\ensuremath{\end{smallmatrix}}}`
`\newcommand{\be}{\begin{enumerate}}

\newcommand{\ee}{\end{enumerate}}`

This does not work:
`\newcommand{\bal}{\begin{align*}}

\newcommand{\eal}{\end{align*}}`
`\newcommand{\verbass}[1]{\begin{verbatim} #1 \end {verbatim}}`

Specifically, I think the \end value is just ignored?

When I try to use `\verbass{Halp}` I get an error: `!File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.`

Obviously I can use \begin{foo} ... \end{foo} at all locations as needed, but really, this should work!

Comment: IMO using an editor/tool with code completion support is a better approach than redefining commands.

Answer (score 5):

How `\begin{verbatim}` works. briefly and roughly.

1. `\begin{verbatim}` is expanded to `\verbatim`.
2. Then `\verbatim` sets category code of each characters to 11. 
   Now all chars is letters.
3. Then `\verbatim` sets font, parindent and calls `\@xverbatim`.
4. `\@xverbatim` catches the end of verbatim using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```
5. Then \end{verbatim} finishes work.

How `\newcommand{\verbass}[1]{\begin{verbatim} #1 \end {verbatim}}` work.

1. First of all `\verbass{Halp}` reads its argument.
2. `#1 --> Halp`
3. `\verbass` expands to `\begin{verbatim} Halp \end {verbatim}`.
    **Important:** backslash of `\end` has category 0 rather than 11. 
    Moreover `{` and `}` have categories 1 and 2  rather than 11.
4. Then `\begin{verbatim}` expands to `\varbatim`. 
    `\varbatim` changes all categories and font. But (**important**)
    the category of backslash (in `\end`) remains equal to 0.
5. Then `\verbatim` calls `\@xverbatim`.
6. `\@xverbatim` tries to catch your argument using the following trick:

   ```
   \def\@xverbatim#1\end{#1\end}
   ```

   but it is impossible because of `\@xverbatim` tries to catch
     `\end` where all letters (`\`,`e`,`n`,`d`) have the category 11.
     But in fact there are four letters with other category code:
     `\` with category 0 and `e`,`n`,`d` with category 11.
7. `\@xverbatim` is trying and trying to find `\end` where backslash (`\`) has category 11 but.... `File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim`

Comment: wow, ok thank you for this. Is there any way to persuade latex to understand that \end is indeed what it's supposed to be, i.e. force the \ to be of category 11?

Comment: yes. it is possible. But it is useless. All argument chars have their own category. `\verbass{ $_^# }` will not work. You should make something like `\verbatim` does.

Comment: I .. don't understand, but ok.      What about the other commands, why does \ee work fine for me but \eal not? Same if I split the verbatim into \begin and \end shorthands, the \end shorthand does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a very brief explanation [here](http://www.tug.org/docs/html/texfaq/faq_15.htm) about verb and verbatim. Basically, LaTeX insists verb and verbatim get the first "look" at their contents.

Answer (score -1):

I am far away from being a professional programmer, but a quick-and-dirty-solutions could be:

```
\newcommand{\myverbatim}[1]{\begin{tt} \detokenize{#1} \end{tt} \\ }
```

The output is not very nice, because linebreaks are ignored. If this is desired one could repeat the command line-by-line (?).

Comment: No; don't suggest something that "is not very nice". There are *far* better ways of doing this. Regarding your use of the `tt` environment, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)